# Caching with glide without loading

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I'm loading pictures from database to grid view using glide, everything is ok. 
But I also need to upload img from my phone to server and put it in grid view.

I get image from my phone, then upload it to server and then I load it from server back to my app. It's make no sense but I can't understand how to cache img with glide without loading.

My question is - how to cache bitmap using glide without loading it?

Comment: When you load the image first time,from the server then i will be cached by the Glide by default. And if you want to load the same image next time. the glide will not make the http request it will send you the cache image automatically.

Comment: Yes, you right. But what if I get image from my phone, and  upload it on server. Can I cache It without loading? I don't want to upload it on server and than load again with glide